# Curriculum vitæ: diverses questions sur les modalités et les types

Tags: curriculum-vitae

J'ai entendu et vu plusieurs formes (une seule page, plusieurs pages) et noms (résumé, académique, synthétique, détaillé, etc.). Néanmoins je n'arrive pas à trouver de renseignements et de modalités précis concernant chaque type.

Quand faut-il faire parvenir un CV d'une page et quand de plusieurs ?
Que signifie résumé et quelles sont les différences entre CV synthétique et détaillé ?

Selon l’Observatoire des discriminations et le Code du travail il ne faut pas rajouter l'âge, ni photo, ni état civil. Cependant en googlant l'on voit que la plupart des modèles comportent ces champs. Alors faut-il rajouter ces renseignements ou pas ?

La forme d'un CV en deux colonnes 
(voir https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/two-column-cv)
est-elle habituelle en France ?

Comment: *Résumé* est un mot anglais quand il s'applique à un CV. Il n'est pas utilisé avec cette acception en France.

Comment: Do you have a link to the law that would prevent **applicants** from adding photos/info re their age/civil status? Forbidding **those doing the hiring** from requiring photos/etc from applicants makes total sense (just as [this law concerning the use of anonymous CVs for larger employers has tried, unsuccessfully until at least 2015, to do since '06](https://fresques.ina.fr/jalons/fiche-media/InaEdu06805/le-cv-anonyme.html), but shifting the burden to applicants by forbidding them from adding these things (as the section you refer to seems to do) would be an approach that only CEOs could love!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about French language -- it would be better on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ (which does have a [france] tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un CV est un document totalement personnel destiné à représenter le caractère de son auteur. On peut y inclure ou non photo, age, état-civil, etc,...

J'ai été short-listé parce que mon CV faisait plus de 500 pages. J'avais inclus l'ensemble de mes publications parce que je savais qu'elles allaient déclancher un interview de curiosité. Mais d'habitude, j'envoie un CV de deux pages (à mon age, une page c'est vraiment pas crédible).

C'est la première fois que je vois un CV sur deux colonne égales, mais il est bien lisible, et va retenir l'attention s'il est formaté joli.